How does heapify maintain max-heap property when both children are larger than the root and their children are also greater than their parents?
I am currently learning about heap sort and I am having trouble understanding the heapify process, particularly when both children of the root are larger than the root itself, and the sub-children (children of the children) are also larger than their parents.
Consider the following initial max-heap structure:
     2
    / \
   3   4
  / \ / \
12  8 9  10

When the heapify process is applied to the root node (value 2), the following steps should occur:

Compare the root (2) with its children (3 and 4).

Swap the root with the largest child (4), resulting in
     4
    / \
   3   2
  / \ / \
12  8 9  10



Recursively heapify the subtree rooted at the swapped node (value 2):

Compare 2 with its children (9 and 10).

Swap 2 with the largest child (10), resulting in
     4
    / \
   3   10
  / \ / \
12  8 9  Fi2



However, the final structure seems incorrect because the parent node (4) is now smaller than one of its children (10). I am confused about how the heapify process ensures the max-heap property is maintained in such scenarios. Could someone explain the correct steps and logic behind heapify in this context?
I followed the standard heapify process to maintain the max-heap property.
I was expecting the heapify process to correctly maintain the max-heap property throughout the heap. Specifically, I anticipated that after the heapify calls, every parent node would be greater than or equal to its children.
However, the final structure appears to violate the max-heap property, as the node with value 4 is smaller than its child with value 10. This confusion led me to question whether I correctly understood the heapify process, especially when both children and their sub-children are larger than the root.
I am expecting someone to explain how the heapify process correctly maintains the max-heap property in this scenario.

The right subtree was originally not even a max heap since 10 was a child of 4. The issue is not with the heapify process.

@Zain, you have answers below. Do you have any feedback?


I was expecting the heapify process to correctly maintain the max-heap property throughout the heap.

This is only guaranteed when the root is the only node that is potentially violating the heap property. The heapify process will only verify and swap values along one path from the root down the tree, so it could not possibly fix any violations of the heap property that might exist along other branches in the tree.
You should not apply this procedure on just any complete binary tree, but one where you are sure the tree is already a heap, with the exception of the value at the root which might need to be swapped-down into a correct place.
When you start out with an array that is not yet a heap, then you first need to turn it into a heap. The way to do that is to take the smallest subtrees in your tree (those with just one or two children which are leaves), and apply the heapify procedure on their root nodes. This will turn those subtrees into little heaps. Then apply heapify on the parent nodes of hose subtrees, which will turn those into larger heaps, ...etc, until you reach the top and the whole tree has become a heap. This is Floyd's algorithm for heap construction.
The next phase in heapsort is to swap the root of the heap with the last element in the array, so that now that largest value is at its destination (at the end of the array). The heap is now one element shorter, and has a value at its root which is not well placed there. Now it is enough to apply the heapify procedure to the root, and the result will be a heap again.
And so you'll repeat that swap with the root and the end of the (shrinking) heap-array, leaving the sorted part out of the heap until the heap section is reduced to nothing and only the sorted array remains.

What this answer is saying is that the Tree doesn’t have Heap-property and therefore should be rebuilt to have Heap-property. heapify() maintains the Heap-property of an Array with Heap-property.

When both children and their sub-children are larger than the root in a max-heap, the heapify process swaps the root with its largest child and repeats this process recursively until the max-heap prop is satisfied. This ensures that the largest element moves to the root, maintaining the max heap property
